# docker sh vs bash variable ${@} expansion - ${@} doesn't work in sh

Tags: bash, docker, ash

It's really straightforward: I am trying to build a docker image where the entrypoint receives the args passed. When I use a `bash` shell, it works. When I use `sh` which comes with `alpine` it doesn't expand; and I think it's because `sh` takes no args at all

Is this possible? And, how?

This doesn't work; meaning `docker run -it myimage arg1 arg2` doesn't receive `arg1 arg2` as the `${@}` requires. I would expect that `gradlew` would be invoked as `./gradlew arg1 arg2`

```
FROM openjdk:8u212-jre-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache jq openjdk8 python3 \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install yq
COPY . /root
WORKDIR /root
RUN ./gradlew dependencies &> /dev/null
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "./gradlew ${@}" ]
```

and this does:

```
FROM gradle
COPY . /home/gradle
RUN ./gradlew -v && ./gradlew dependencies &> /dev/null
ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c", "./gradlew ${@}" ]
```

When I dig into what `sh` really is:

```sh
/bin # which sh
/bin/sh
/bin # ls -al /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 May  9  2019 /bin/sh -> /bin/busybox
```

Comment: `it works` what "works" and how and how do you check it? `&>` is a bash extension.

Comment: Often `sh` is an alias to `bash` or `dash`. I'd check what the real shell is, or specify what shell you want in `ENTRYPOINT` and avoid any guessing there.

Comment: updated to reflect your comment @Robert

Comment: Can you respond to @KamilCuk's comment? What does "doesn't work" mean? Also note that in both versions you are misusing the `$@` variable (which, when unquoted, is identical to `$*`), and the way you've written things your script will lose its first argument (see the documentation for `-c` in the `bash(1)` man page).

Comment: @larsks I have answered hist question as well. And, the `${@}` is quoted along with `"gradlew"`

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno, JSON quoting does not substitute for shell quoting. It would need to be `["bash", "-c", "./gradlew \"$@\""]` for the `$@` to be quoted from the shell's perspective. (You could use `"./gradlew \"${@}\""` but there's no point whatsoever; the extra `{}`s buy you no advantage at all).

Comment: ...that said, I don't know why you'd involve bash in this in any whatsoever, instead of just running `ENTRYPOINT [ "./gradlew" ]`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - yup, I discovered that and changed it (re gradlew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about "gradle", so let's replace your call to `gradlew` with an `echo` statement in order to diagnose things:

```
FROM openjdk:8u212-jre-alpine
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "echo ${@}" ]
```

If I build an image named `cbtest` and run it like this:

```
docker run --rm cbtest arg1 arg2
```

I get as output:

```
arg2
```

Which means it's mostly working, except as I noted in the comments you're losing your first argument. If we take a look at the `bash(1)` man page, we find:

```
-c  If  the  -c option is present, then commands are read from the
    first non-option argument  command_string.   If  there  are
    arguments  after  the  command_string,  the  first  argument is
    assigned to $0 and any remaining argu‐ ments are assigned to the
    positional parameters.  The assignment to $0  sets the name of the
    shell, which is used in warning and error messages.
```

The key phrase is **the first argument is assigned to $0**.  The
argument `$0` is the name of the currently running program, rather
than an argument to the program.  You need to add a `--` to your `sh`
command line to indicate that it should stop trying to parse arguments
and just pass everything as parameters to the called script. Again from the man page:

```
--  A -- signals the end of options and disables further option
    processing.  Any arguments  after the -- are treated as filenames
    and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.
```

This gives us:

```
FROM openjdk:8u212-jre-alpine
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "echo ${@}", "--" ]
```

If I run the same command as above, I now get:

```
arg1 arg2
```

So that's great.

I mentioned in the comments that you're misusing the `${@}` variable
because you're not quoting it. You might *think* you are, but the
`/bin/sh` you're calling doesn't know anything about those quotes; the
command passed to the shell is simply:

```
./gradlew ${@}
```

...with no quotes around `${@}`.  Let's modify the script slightly so
that we can see the difference; consider this script:

```
FROM openjdk:8u212-jre-alpine
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "for arg in ${@}; do echo $arg; done", "--" ]
```

If I run the image like this:

```
docker run --rm cbtest "arg with spaces" "second arg"
```

I get as output:

```
arg
with
spaces
second
arg
```

As you can see, the script is seeing five arguments rather than two.
We can fix that with proper quoting:

```
FROM openjdk:8u212-jre-alpine
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "for arg in \"${@}\"; do echo $arg; done", "--" ]
```

Which given the above input produces:

```
arg with spaces
second arg
```

So your `ENTRYPOINT` should probably look like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "./gradlew \"${@}\"", "--" ]
```